# Database cleaner freezes the system in truncation mode

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-5, database-cleaner

more info here https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/issues/475

Basically I can't run my specs after Rails Upgrade in `truncation` mode, system freezes, I am using `mysql + rspec-rails`

Comment: Could you add more information about this issue? What problem did you have in your database?

Comment: I totally stopped mysql and then start, dropped DB and then recreated it